# Need help to construct tabular form from attributes

Tags: database, database-design

I am confused with some thing that how i can construct tabular form from a list of attributes. Should I make it different table or just put all together?

These are the attributes -- >

- Patient Name
- List item
- Patient Address
- Patient Contact Number
- Patient Date of  Birth
- Patient Gender
- Patient’s Mother Name
- Patient’s Father Name
- Doctor Name
- Doctor Address
- Doctor Home Tel
- Doctor Mobile Tel
- Doctor   Qualification
- Doctor date of birth
- Appointment Date
- Appointment Time
- Appointment Doctor Visit
- Date Visit
- Time Visit
- reason Diagnosis
- Prescription
- Date of bill
- Total bill charge

So, should I make it in different table or in same table, any example where I can refer on it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the fields which you have listed are atomic and some are repeating. Those fields should be separated into at least three different tables:

```
PATIENTS
ID
Name
Address
Contact Number
Date of Birth
Gender
Mother Name
Father Name

DOCTORS
ID
Name
Address
Home Tel (it may be necessary to move phone numbers into a separate table)
Mobile Tel (what happens if you have three numbers for a doctor?)
Qualification
Date of birth (this seems unnecessary)

APPOINTMENTS
ID
Patient (foreign key to patients table)
Doctor (foreign key to doctors table)
Date
Time
Diagnosis
Prescription
Date of bill 
Total bill charge
```

Bills should probably be in a separate table; what if you issue more than one bill for an appointment. You may also need a table called TESTS which would contain the names (and cost) of various lab tests and a table called APPOINTESTS (or something similar) which would store whichever tests had been performed for whichever appointment.

Your question reads as if this is an assignment for a course, in which case you should add the 'homework' tag.

Comment: (Y)  Great really appreciate it

Comment: @JahidulIslam: if what I have written answers your question, then 'accept' the answer (click on the green arrow).

Comment: You have been ignore visit_date and visit_time, is it not necessary, you provide the three table it is in 1NF

Comment: @JahidulIslam: if I understand your comment correctly, 'visit_date' is now appointments.date, and 'visit_time' is appointments.time.

Comment: Ok, so, the three table should in 2nf form, isn't it, I am really confused with this